# Can anyone understand why the value loss of my PPO agent does not decline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I am training a PPO model based on PyTorch for a multiagent reinforcement learning application. I am using petting zoo to implement my environment. The environment is a space in which I want my agents to search. It is a continuous setting and my state space is a simple normalized vector. My agent is based on this implementation: https://github.com/alek5k/cleanrl/blob/53a3d0ffab83f7b0698479d79cdc0aee94f1f83d/cleanrl/ppo_pettingzoo.py#L85

For some reason, I cannot get the agent to learn anything, it seems to be something related to the evaluation, because my value loss does not go down. This leads me to the conclusion that there is a bug in my implementation. Can anyone see why this agent fails?

Here is my action and value function:

```
def get_action(self, x, action=None):

        x.to(self.device)
        net = self.network(x)
        dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        action_mean = self.actor_mean(dropout(net))
        action_logstd = self.actor_logstd.expand_as(action_mean)
        action_std = torch.exp(action_logstd).to(self.device)
        probs = Normal(action_mean, action_std)
        if action is None:
            action = probs.sample().to(self.device)
        return action, probs.log_prob(action).sum(1), probs.entropy().sum(1)

    def get_value(self, x):
        x = x.to(self.device)
        return self.critic(self.network(x))
```

My current model (I have tried many others):

```
self.network = nn.Sequential(
            layer_init(nn.Linear(12, 64)),
            layer_init(nn.Linear(64, 128)),
            layer_init(nn.Linear(128, 64)),
            nn.ReLU(),

        ).to(self.device)
self.actor_mean = nn.Sequential(layer_init(
            nn.Linear(64, np.prod(self.env.action_space.shape)), std=1).to(self.device),
            nn.Tanh())
self.actor_logstd = nn.Parameter(
            torch.zeros(1, np.prod(self.env.action_space.shape)))
self.critic = nn.Sequential(layer_init(
            nn.Linear(64, 32), std=1).to(self.device),
            nn.Tanh(),
            layer_init(
            nn.Linear(32, 1), std=1).to(self.device))
self.optimizer = optim.Adam(
            self.parameters(), lr=self.args.learning_rate, eps=1e-5, weight_decay=0.1)
```

This is my train function:

```
def train(self, plot=False):
        global_step = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        next_obs = self.env.reset()
        next_done = torch.zeros(self.args.num_envs).to(self.device)
        num_updates = self.args.total_timesteps // self.args.batch_size
        for update in range(1, num_updates+1):
            # Annealing the rate if instructed to do so.
            if self.args.anneal_lr:
                frac = 1.0 - (update - 1.0) / num_updates
                lrnow = self.lr(frac)
                self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = lrnow

            for step in range(0, self.args.num_steps):
                global_step += 1 * self.args.num_envs
                self.obs[step] = next_obs
                self.dones[step] = next_done

                with torch.no_grad():
                    self.values[step] = self.get_value(
                        self.obs[step]).flatten()
                    action, logproba, _ = self.get_action(self.obs[step])

                self.actions[step] = action
                self.logprobs[step] = logproba

                next_obs, rs, ds, infos = self.env.step(torch.clamp(
                    action, self.env.action_space.low.mean(), self.env.action_space.high.mean()))
                self.rewards[step], next_done = rs.view(
                    -1), torch.Tensor(ds).to(self.device)

            # bootstrap reward if not done. reached the batch limit
            with torch.no_grad():
                last_value = self.get_value(
                    next_obs.to(self.device)).reshape(1, -1)
                if self.args.gae:
                    advantages = torch.zeros_like(self.rewards).to(self.device)
                    lastgaelam = 0
                    for t in reversed(range(self.args.num_steps)):
                        if t == self.args.num_steps - 1:
                            nextnonterminal = 1.0 - next_done
                            nextvalues = last_value
                        else:
                            nextnonterminal = 1.0 - self.dones[t+1]
                            nextvalues = self.values[t+1]
                        delta = self.rewards[t] + self.args.gamma * \
                            nextvalues * nextnonterminal - self.values[t]
                        advantages[t] = lastgaelam = delta + self.args.gamma * \
                            self.args.gae_lambda * nextnonterminal * lastgaelam
                    returns = advantages + self.values
                else:
                    returns = torch.zeros_like(self.rewards).to(self.device)
                    for t in reversed(range(self.args.num_steps)):
                        if t == self.args.num_steps - 1:
                            nextnonterminal = 1.0 - next_done
                            next_return = last_value
                        else:
                            nextnonterminal = 1.0 - self.dones[t+1]
                            next_return = returns[t+1]
                        returns[t] = self.rewards[t] + self.args.gamma * \
                            nextnonterminal * next_return
                    advantages = returns - self.values

            # flatten the batch
            b_obs = self.obs.reshape((-1,)+self.env.observation_space.shape)
            b_logprobs = self.logprobs.reshape(-1)
            b_actions = self.actions.reshape(
                (-1,)+self.env.action_space.shape)
            b_advantages = advantages.reshape(-1)
            b_returns = returns.reshape(-1)
            b_values = self.values.reshape(-1)

            # Optimizaing the policy and value network
            target_agent = Agent(self.env, self.hp_dict).to(self.device)
            inds = np.arange(self.args.batch_size,)
            stopped = 0
            for i_epoch_pi in range(self.args.update_epochs):
                np.random.shuffle(inds)
                target_agent.load_state_dict(self.state_dict())
                for start in range(0, self.args.batch_size, self.args.minibatch_size):
                    end = start + self.args.minibatch_size
                    minibatch_ind = inds[start:end]
                    mb_advantages = b_advantages[minibatch_ind]
                    if self.args.norm_adv:
                        mb_advantages = (mb_advantages - mb_advantages.mean()
                                         ) / (mb_advantages.std() + 1e-8)

                    _, newlogproba, entropy = self.get_action(
                        b_obs[minibatch_ind], b_actions[minibatch_ind])
                    ratio = (newlogproba - b_logprobs[minibatch_ind]).exp()

                    # Stats
                    approx_kl = (
                        b_logprobs[minibatch_ind] - newlogproba).mean()

                    # Policy loss
                    pg_loss1 = -mb_advantages * ratio
                    pg_loss2 = -mb_advantages * \
                        torch.clamp(ratio, 1-self.args.clip_coef,
                                    1+self.args.clip_coef)
                    pg_loss = torch.max(pg_loss1, pg_loss2).mean()
                    entropy_loss = entropy.mean()

                    # Value loss
                    new_values = self.get_value(b_obs[minibatch_ind]).view(-1)
                    if self.args.clip_vloss:
                        v_loss_unclipped = (
                            (new_values - b_returns[minibatch_ind]) ** 2)
                        v_clipped = b_values[minibatch_ind] + torch.clamp(
                            new_values - b_values[minibatch_ind], -self.args.clip_coef, self.args.clip_coef)
                        v_loss_clipped = (
                            v_clipped - b_returns[minibatch_ind])**2
                        v_loss_max = torch.max(
                            v_loss_unclipped, v_loss_clipped)
                        v_loss = 0.5 * v_loss_max.mean()
                    else:
                        v_loss = 0.5 * \
                            ((new_values -
                             b_returns[minibatch_ind]) ** 2).mean()

                    loss = pg_loss - self.args.ent_coef * entropy_loss + v_loss * self.args.vf_coef

                    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                    loss.backward()
                    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(
                        self.parameters(), self.args.max_grad_norm)
                    self.optimizer.step()

                if self.args.kle_stop:
                    if approx_kl > self.args.target_kl:
                        stopped += 1
                        break
                if self.args.kle_rollback:
                    if (b_logprobs[minibatch_ind] - self.get_action(b_obs[minibatch_ind], b_actions[minibatch_ind])[1]).mean() > self.args.target_kl:
                        self.load_state_dict(target_agent.state_dict())
                        break
```

I have tried many different reward signals, in many different scales, without any luck. I have tried many different models, and hyperparameters. I expected the value loss, and the policy loss to go down, but the value loss flattens out, and does not move. I have tried to see whether the bug could be in the environment, but after a lot of testing and logging, I have not found any error there.